# SQL Server : query with incorrect SUM result

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server query is supposed to get a count of each customer's number of orders, and the `SUM` of their reward points. For most customers the result is accurate (most people only have one or two orders). For a few people, the result is wildly off.

Here's the original query:

```
SELECT 
    c.email,
    c.lastlogindate,
    c.custenabled,
    c.maillist,
    d.GroupName,
    COUNT(o.orderid) AS orders,
    SUM(r.points) AS total_points
FROM 
    ((customers c
      LEFT JOIN orders o ON (c.contactid = o.ocustomerid AND o.ostep = 'step 5')
     )
     LEFT JOIN discount_group d ON c.discount = d.id
    )
LEFT JOIN 
    customer_rewards r ON r.contactid = c.contactid
WHERE 
    c.last_update > '2014-02-01'
OR c.lastlogindate > '2014-02-01'
GROUP BY 
    c.email, c.custenabled, c.maillist, c.lastlogindate, d.GroupName;
```

For one example, customerid 1234 has placed 21 orders, totaling 2724 points. This will report that he has placed 441 orders (21 * 21) valued at 57204 points (2724 * 21). The raw data is fine, but each order row is being duplicated by the amount of orders they placed (but not for most customers...)

If I change the query to this:

```
SELECT 
    o.orderid,
    c.email,
    COUNT(o.orderid) AS orders,
    SUM(r.points) AS total_points
FROM 
    ((customers c
      INNER JOIN orders o ON (c.contactid = o.ocustomerid AND o.ostep = 'step 5')
     )
    )
INNER JOIN 
    customer_rewards r ON r.contactid = c.contactid
WHERE 
    c.last_update > '2014-02-01'
OR c.lastlogindate > '2014-02-01'
GROUP BY 
    c.email, o.orderid;
```

The aggregate functions are calculated properly, but it will display one result for each order placed. So it will show "Customer 1234/21 orders/2724 points", 21 times.

I did remove the 'discount_group' join in the second query, but that was just to make it easier to read and change. That hasn't had any effect on results.

Comment: can you give sql to create the tables and some sample rows ? also, can you show the expected output table and the wrong results you are getting ?

Comment: Your query is generating a cartesian product for each customer.  This happens when you join along independent dimensions.  The solution is to aggregate in subqueries before doing joins.

Comment: It looks to me like the discount_group table has more than one row per id value.  Is this the case?

Comment: @Hogan No that isn't the case, and you can pretty well ignore the discount_group table in this problem, since removing it from the query doesn't affect anything for these aggregate functions.

Comment: It's probably "customer_rewards" that has one "rewards" record per "order".  But you are only using the "contactid" to do the join.  You need to join on the "orderid"...  or else, as Gordon Linoff suggested, do the rewards aggregation in a subquery

Comment: As Gordon's comment mentioned, this is b/c you have multiple `orders` per customer and multiple `customer_rewards` per customer, so when you join the two together, you get each `customer_rewards` record applied to each `orders` record. You need to aggregate the order count and rewards amount before doing the join, using a subquery or common table expression http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using common table expressions to aggregate your results.

Note: this will not show customers that have 0 orders or 0 rewards points.  If you would like to show these, change the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

```
WITH cteOrders AS
(
    SELECT o.ocustomerid, orderCount = count(*)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.ostep = 'step 5'
    GROUP BY o.ocustomerid
)
, cteRewards as
(
    SELECT cr.contactid, total_points = SUM(cr.points)
    FROM customer_rewards cr
    GROUP BY cr.contactid
)
SELECT 
    c.email,
    o.orderCount as orders,
    r.total_points
FROM 
    customers c
    INNER JOIN cteOrders o ON c.contactid = o.ocustomerid
    INNER JOIN cteRewards r ON r.contactid = c.contactid 
WHERE 
    c.last_update > '2014-02-01'
OR c.lastlogindate > '2014-02-01'
;
```

Or using subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    c.email,
    o.orderCount as orders,
    r.total_points
FROM 
    customers c
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT o.ocustomerid, orderCount = count(*)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.ostep = 'step 5'
    GROUP BY o.ocustomerid
    ) o ON c.contactid = o.ocustomerid
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT cr.contactid, total_points = SUM(cr.points)
    FROM customer_rewards cr
    GROUP BY cr.contactid
    ) r ON r.contactid = c.contactid 
WHERE 
    c.last_update > '2014-02-01'
OR c.lastlogindate > '2014-02-01'
;
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to verify this worked on test data. Unfortunately for the real data I access the db via an API (that takes an SQL string as an argument) and it appears that CTE's do not work through that API. :(. I will mark this as correct, but if you can think of any other way I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll post an update in a few minutes after I get back to a computer. Short version is replace cteOrders and cteRewards with each query text including parenthesis after the "as" for each cte

Comment: Might also be able to add a semi colon before the word "with" and get it to work using your api.

Comment: Updated answer to include subqueries instead of CTEs